# resetCounter() function not being accessed or not working as expected in my python Tkinter program

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a tkinter program where I want one button (button1) always on the screen. Each time the first button (button1) is clicked a new button (button2) should appear 30 pixels below the previous one. To do this I am using a counter and adding the y value of the new button (button2) to 30 multiplied by counter. When any one of the new buttons (button2) are clicked, I want the counter to reset so the new buttons start appearing where the first one was again. In other words, when button1 is clicked, button2 should appear in the original spot again.

I do this by accessing the resetCounter() function which should set the counter to 0 again.

Where I am having an issue is my counter is never reseting and the new buttons (button2) just keep appearing lower than the last even after one of them is clicked. I'm not sure if my resetCounter() function is never being accessed or if there is something wrong with the resetCounter() function. Please help thank you!

My code looks something like this:

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.geometry("300x300")
window.configure(background='gray')

counter = 0
def resetCounter(counter):
   counter = 0

def button1Clicked():
   global counter
   button2 = Button(window, text="click me when ready", command=lambda:[(resetCounter(counter)), button2.destroy()])
   button2.place(x=50, y=(100 + (counter*30)))
   counter += 1

button1 = Button(window, text="click me", command=button1Clicked)
button1.place(x=0, y=0)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: I want the counter to reset every time button 2 is clicked. That way once button 2 is clicked they start appearing in the initial placement

Comment: I see, you haven't `global counter` inside `def resetCounter(...`

Comment: Ah yes. So should look like this: `def resetCounter(): global counter counter = 0`

Comment: That's correct, you have to use `global ...` if you want to assign a value to a `global` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you stovfl

`resetCounter` should like like this:

```
def resetCounter():
   global counter
   counter = 0
```